# jquery autocomplete: add extra parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a dropdown called Category, and a table with 2 columns Language and Name.

Category will determine the scope (Books, Magazines, etc.)
Language is also a dropdown with fixed list of values (English, Spanish, etc.)

Now I need the values of Name to be autocompleted with the source scoped by both the global Category, as well as its row's Language

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="Row.Language"></select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <textarea name="Row.Name"></textarea>
    </td>
<tr>
```

What I have tried so far:

```
$('select[name="Row.Language"]').change(function () {
    getNameAutoComplete($(this).parent().parent());
});

function getNameAutoComplete(row) {
    var lang = $(row).find("select[name='Row.Language']").val();
    console.log("Outer: lang = " + lang);
    $(row).find('textarea[name="Row.Name"]').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, callback) {
            var cat = $("#ddlCategory").val();
            console.log("Inner: lang = " + lang);
            encodeddata = { category: cat, language: lang, term: request.term };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: getNameAutoCompleteListActionUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: encodeddata,
                beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
                    $("#loadingAnim").show();
                },
                complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    $("#loadingAnim").hide();
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    callback(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        }
     });
}
```

As you may have noticed, this doesn't work.
The inner `lang` is always null, whereas the outer `lang` has the correct selected value.

Appreciate if you guys can give me some advice how to achieve this.

====

Added jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/harryt/mdktg4mt/1/

And strange enough, it works on jsfiddle! Although if you look closely, the jsfiddle url above, `lang` is not defined (black instead of blue color) inside the `source: function (request, callback)`

Comment: try defining lang as a global variable outside `getVanillaUnderlyingAutoComplete`

Comment: but there will be many rows, how do I map back which global lang to use for which row?

Comment: can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: added fiddle in the post